# Iframe content hidden unless hover in inspector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm displaying an iframe inside a modal.
I can navigate inside this iframe through a booking process of 3 pages.

From time to time (not everytime), the content of this iframe doesn't render properly / appears hidden when i switch page, like if i had put opacity: 0 on the iframe content.

The html elements are present, i can click on the buttons inside the iframe, even if they are not visible, or select / copy text content.

=================================

Hovering the iframe inside the inspector make all the iframe content appears.

Resizing the window make all the iframe content appears.

Modifying the iframe style height / width in pixel through javascript make all the iframe content appears

=================================

Modify the style opacity of the iframe content, the iframe node, the iframe parent node through javascript doesn't make the content appears

Modify the style visibility of the iframe content, the iframe node, the iframe parent node through javascript doesn't make the content appears

Modifying the iframe / iframe parent node style height / width in % through javascript doesn't make the content appears

Triggering a window resize doesn't make the content appears.

================================

More weird, this bug appears only on chromium, i'am not able to reproduce it on firefox.
I am using chromium 87.0.4280.66 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04.
I haven't update chromium recently, never encountered this bug before and don't know why this is suddenly appearing.

Does anyone have encountered this bug and know how to fix it ?

=======> Solution found, see below

Comment: would be helpful if you share your code

Comment: What browsers are affected by this "blanking"?

Comment: i didn't test on all browser,  i was able to reproduce it on google chrome and chromium, wasn't able to reproduce it on firefox. I didn't encountered this before, so i assume its a "feature"/bug in chromium release  87.0.4280.66 (17 november 2020)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that webkit can "fail" on redrawing correctly the content. Triggering the redrawing on iframe load fix the problem.

You can trigger the webkit reflow/redraw by modifying some css property, for example:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)'; // redraw element
element.style.webkitTransform = 'TranslateZ(0)'; // redraw element
```

Be aware that if the css value don't change, the redraw is not done:

```
 element.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)'; // redraw element
 element.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)'; // redraw not done
```

The solution for me was to force the redraw of iframe/iframe parent node on each load event, doesn't know exactly why, but did the job....

```
var i = 0;

var redraw = function(){
   i = (i+1) % 2;

   if(i == 0)
   {
      iframes.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.style.mozTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.style.msTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.style.oTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.style.transform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';

      iframes.parentNode.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.mozTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.msTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.oTransform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.transform = 'scale(1) translateZ(0)';
    }
    else
    {
       iframes.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.style.mozTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.style.msTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.style.oTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.style.transform = 'scale(1)';

      iframes.parentNode.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.mozTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.msTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.oTransform = 'scale(1)';
      iframes.parentNode.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    }

};

iframes.onload = function(){
  redraw();
}
```

Starting to hate css/js again....